# PHP Function __Autoload()

Tags: php

Alright, i might be coming off as a complete and total idiot for this question. But how exactly does the __autoload function work in php? I've never been able to get it to work and cannot find a good tutorial explaining how said function works.

Comment: There you go: [PHP autoload docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)

Comment: I've read through that, and it does not really help me. seeing as i've followed the PHP.net documents and still cannot get it to work

Answer (score 3):

the __autoload function gets called when you reference a class who's definition is unknown to php. you must define the logic on how to load the definition of such class in your `__autoload` function. for example as follows.

```
function __autoload($classname) {
    $filename = "./". $classname .".php";
    include_once($filename);
}

//when you say $a = new someclass(); autoload gets called with $classname = "someclass"
```

alternatively you can use any function as a autoload function by registering that function as a autoload function using `spl_autoload_register`.

```
function my_autoloader($class) {
    include 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');
```

you can also chain autoload functions, by returning false when the class definition is not found `spl_autoload_register` will call the next function in the chain.

```
function my_autoloader1($class) {
    $file = 'classes1/' . $class . '.class.php';
    if (!is_file($file)) return false;
    include $file;
}

function my_autoloader2($class) {
    include 'classes2/' . $class . '.class.php';
}

spl_autoload_register(array('my_autoloader1', 'my_autoloader2'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically, it gives you a chance to load class definitions on demand.

As an example, suppose I have code that is creating a new `Foo` object - but I have not defined the `Foo` class.

Before PHP just gives up and generates an error, it will call `__autoload('Foo')`. If the `Foo` class is still undefined once the `__autoload()` function has completed, then it'll generate the error.

An effective `__autoload()` function will know where the file is that defines the requested class, and will `include()` the needed file - so that when it returns, the class is now defined.

A common autoload scheme is to replace underscores (`_`) in the classname with directory separators in order to load the correct file. So the class `My_Foo_Class` would be defined in the file `"My/Foo/Class.php"`.